# Is there a SWAT model integration for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hydrology, modelling, watershed

I am trying to use SWAT (Soil and Water Assessment Tool) for watershed management activities.
It is a set of commandline tools and needs a complex set of input data some of which can be generated from DEMs.

There is a plugin available for ArcGIS and MapWindow which makes life easier. I want to know if there is any project/work going on to integrate SWAT with QGIS.

Or, is there any other soil and watershed modelling tool available for QGIS which can generate/estimate runoffs, sediment load, erosion vulnerability etc. from relevant input data like rainfall, slopes, stream network, soil type, land use etc.

Comment: Could be of help: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228956997_Assessment_of_open_source_GIS_software_for_water_resources_management_in_developing_countries/file/9c96051d7ce905ff13.pdf

Comment: @Chad Cooper Thanks! I would probably need to spend a couple of nights on this!

Answer (score 3):

A beta version of QSWAT was released [here](http://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/). According to the mentioned requirements, QSWAT currently runs with the 32-bit version of QGIS 2.6.1 on Windows.

Comment: New version at https://swat.tamu.edu/software/plus/